# How do I install g77?

Tags: installation, fortran

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (32bit-i386) in my desktop PC. I need g77 compiler for some specific applications. The app can only be installed after having g77 compiler. This specific app is designed based on g77 fortran compiler and can't be used with gfortran which is the standard available compiler in 12.04 LTS.

And guide me the procedure to install g77 in 12.04. I have been trying `apt-get update & apt-get install g77` after changing the `sources.list` file. After processing I am able to install g77 but when i try to compile a fortran program, it shows error

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find crt1.o: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find crti.o: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Please help me. I m struggling a lot to fix this.

Answer (score 2):

Since `g77` is no longer supported, you'd need to download it from older Ubuntu repositories.

You can download it from the [Ubuntu Hardy Packages page](http://packages.ubuntu.com/hardy-updates/g77-3.4). Below is the screenshot of the page.

[image]

- Download the `amd64` or `i386` version depending on your architecture.
- As you can see from the screenshot, the package depends on `gcc-3.4`, `gcc-3.4-base`, `libc6`, and `libg2c0-dev`, you'd have to install them first, and probably remove your newer version of these packages.

I recommend downloading **Ubuntu 8.04 (Hardy Heron)**, and installing it on a virtual machine. You can then download the `g77` package and install it directly.